# Transfer files from one table to another in impala

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala

I have two tables in impala and I want to move the data from one to another.
Both tables have hdfs path like

```
/user/hive/db/table1 or table2/partitiona/partitionb/partitionc/file
```

I know the procedure with `INSERT INTO` to move the data from one table to another.
What I do not know is how to move also the files in the hdfs paths or if this happens automatically with the `INSERT INTO statement`

Also, if a table is sorted in the creation settings, if any data insert into it it will be sorted too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens automatically and done by hive. When you do `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2`, hive copies data from `/user/hive/db/table1` to `table2/partitiona/partitionb/partitionc/file`.
You do not have to move anything. You may need to analyze table1 for better performance.

Answer to your second question, if you use `sort by` while creating table1, then data will be automatically sorted by in table1 irrespective of data sorted or unsorted in table2.